# XSLT get nth position of an element betwean specific other elements

Tags: xml, xslt, global-variables

In my `input.xml` I have both `<note>` and `<bignote>` tags, so in the output I try to make each occurrence of both of this two tags follow a same numbering chain.

###### input.xml

```xml
<body>
    <p>
        dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
        <div>
            dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
            <note>LOREM</note>
            dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
        </div>
        <gibnote>IPSUM</gibnote>
    </p>
    <p>
        dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
        <note>DOLOR</note>
        dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
    </p>
        dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
        <bignote>SIT</bignote>
    <div>
        <note>AMET</note>
    </div>
        dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
</body>
```

###### stylesheet.xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="note">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:number level="any" format="1. "/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bignote">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:number level="any" format="1. "/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
    BIG
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

###### output.xml should be

```xml
<body>
    <p>
        dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
        <div>
            dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
            <note rank="note1">1. LOREM</note>
            dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
        </div>
        <note rank="note2">2. BIGIPSUM</note>
    </p>
    <p>
        dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
        <note rank="note3">3. DOLOR</note>
        dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
    </p>
        dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
        <note rank="note4">4. BIGSIT</note>
    <div>
        <note rank="note5">5. AMET</note>
    </div>
        dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
</body>
```

Unfortunatly, the numbering follow a different chain between `<note>`s and `<bignote>`s.

I get this kind of numbering:

```
1. note Lorem
1. bignote Ipsum
2. note Dolor
2. bignote sit
3. note amet
```

So, how to make both of `<note>`s and `<bignote>`s follow the same numbering suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `count` attribute of `xsl:number`. This is a pattern which defines which nodes are counted to calculate the number.

The ['Numbering' section of the XSLT 1.0 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#element-number) says:

> The `count` attribute is a pattern that specifies what nodes should be
> counted at those levels. If count attribute is not specified, then it
> defaults to the pattern that matches any node with the same node type
> as the current node and, if the current node has an expanded-name,
> with the same expanded-name as the current node.

Here I modified your stylesheet so that it counts either `note` or `bignote` elements.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="note">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:number count="bignote|note" level="any" format="1. "/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bignote">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:number count="bignote|note" level="any" format="1. "/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
    BIG
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Note that your result is not OP's expected result.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT, you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="note | bignote">
    <xsl:variable name="num">
        <xsl:number count="note | bignote" level="any"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <note rank="note{$num}">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($num, '0. ')"/>
        <xsl:if test="self::bignote">BIG</xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </note>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```